# Oracle Group by multiple condition

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I had a query to group types with sum of prices

```
SELECT t.type, sum(t.price) AS TOTAL
FROM table1 t
WHERE t.entry_date = & entryDate
GROUP BY t.type;
```

It works correctly and returns

```
+-----------+-----------+
|   TYPE    |   TOTAL   |
+-----------+-----------+
|           |   741,5   | 
|   type1   |   108,54  |
|   type2   |   216,35  |
+-----------+-----------+
```

In table some of the rows don't have a type name.
I want to add a case to check if exists add its price to type1 so
I tried something like

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN t.id = k.orderno AND length(k.invoice_no) < 12 
             THEN 'type1' ELSE t.type END
        ) AS TYPE, 
        SUM(t.price) AS TOTAL
FROM table1 t, table2 k
WHERE t.entry_date = & entryDate
GROUP BY TYPE;
```

It gives

> ora-00937 not a single-group group function

I also tried group by when case but it didn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing your table definitions and what the columns are used for it is difficult to answer; however, it could be as simple as:

```sql
SELECT COALESCE( t.type, t.price ) AS type,
       sum(t.price) AS TOTAL
FROM   table1 t
WHERE  t.entry_date = &entryDate
GROUP BY
       t.type;
```

Or, if you want to join another table then you want to use a join condition (and, preferably, the ANSI join syntax rather the legacy comma join syntax):

```sql
SELECT CASE
       WHEN COALESCE( LENGTH(k.invoice_no), 0 ) < 12 
       THEN 'type1' || t.price
       ELSE t.type
       END AS TYPE, 
       SUM(t.price) AS TOTAL
FROM   table1 t
       LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 k
       ON ( t.id = k.orderno )
WHERE  t.entry_date = &entryDate
GROUP BY
       CASE
       WHEN COALESCE( LENGTH(k.invoice_no), 0 ) < 12 
       THEN 'type1' || t.price
       ELSE t.type
       END;
```

Comment: Thanks, LEFT OUTER JOIN solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `group by` accordingly as follows:

```
select Case When t.id = k.orderno 
             and length(k.invoice_no) < 12 
            THEN 'type1' 
            ELSE t.type 
       END AS TYPE, 
 sum(t.price) as TOTAL
 from table1 t, table2 k
 where t.entry_date = &entryDate
 group by Case When t.id = k.orderno 
                and length(k.invoice_no) < 12 
               THEN 'type1' 
               ELSE t.type 
          END;
```

Comment: I tried the solution and it returned all data. It seems entry_date not worked.

Comment: entrydate must work and what you are passing as entrydate? Question was related to GROUP BY

Comment: Yes in first query if i gave entry date as 19.10.2020 it only gathered that days type. In this one i entered same value but it returned 456670033,35 which seems to all data value

Comment: @ErdiAtalay That is because you have `CROSS JOIN`ed the two tables.

Comment: Sorry i'm not good at sql so i could'nt think to join tables